# Программа для сравнения двух файлов?

Tags: diff

Какие есть программы для быстрого сравнения двух файлов JavaScript, HTML, CSS, аналогично VCS-системам? То есть, передаёшь два файла, а программа показывает, чем они отличаются, и в каких строках. Но для любых локальных файлов, без какой-то централизованной системы и установки.

Comment: Быстрее и удобнее сразу сравнивать файлы в том же текстовом редакторе/IDE, которым Вы пользуетесь, без установки дополнительных программ. В Sublime Text 3 мне пока не доводилось наблюдать сбоев в работе служащего для этой цели плагина [**SublimeFileDiffs**](https://github.com/colinta/SublimeFileDiffs). Спасибо.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что ответы по рекоммендации ПО субъективны. Тем более, что список уже есть и поддерживается на вики - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_comparison_tools

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На будущее:

- Когда просите посоветовать программу, всегда указывайте свою операционную систему.
- Здесь подобные вопросы закрываются, специально для них служит сайт [Software Reccomendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Быстрее и удобнее не открывать лишний раз сторонние программы, а когда всё и сразу совершается в одном редакторе/IDE.

### Решения для Sublime Text 3

#### Быстрое

Плагин [**FileDiffs**](https://github.com/colinta/SublimeFileDiffs), документация там же, по ссылке.

[image: Пример работы плагина FileDiffs]

Выделяются сами различия между файлами и приводятся номера строк — лично мне этого вполне хватает.

#### Продвинутое

Плагин Sublimerge 3, инструкция по установке в конце [**страницы**](http://www.sublimerge.com/sm3/). Он Freemium, но если не желаете отдавать деньги, придётся только иногда (достаточно нечасто) терпеть всплывающее окно с предложением его купить. Пример работы:

[image: Sublimerge]

Из преимуществ отметил бы возможность интеграции с системами контроля версий SVN, Git и Mercurial (Bazaar пока не поддерживается). Например, чтобы сравнить файл в локальном хранилище с любой из его версий на удалённом репозитории, необходимо кликнуть где-нибудь в тексте этого файла правой кнопкой мыши, в появляющемся контекстном меню <kbd>Sublimerge</kbd> → <kbd>Compare to revision...</kbd> → выбираем требуемую версию для сравнения.

Подробности в [**документации**](http://www.sublimerge.com/sm3/docs/quick-start.html).

Comment: А не составить ли вам единый Вики ответ из всех остальных, по аналогии со списками литературы? ;-)

Comment: @Kromster, я только за, правда, скорее всего, вопрос скоро закроют. Сам могу разве что нагуглить решения для других продвинутых редакторов/IDE, но, так как ими — в отличие от FileDiffs — лично не пользуюсь, в вынесении оценочного суждения буду некомпетентен. Если кто-то другой составит — пожалуйста.

Comment: ИМХО как раз перевод вопроса в вики спасет его от закрытя. И как раз в вики все оценочное суждение будет не нужно - останется просто список с фичами (такими как платформа и платность/опенсорсность)

Comment: Правда все уже сделали до нас - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_comparison_tools

Answer (score 5):

Если под Linux, то идеально подходит встроенная утилита **diff**.

Answer (score 4):

Советую посмотреть в сторону [Winmerge](http://winmerge.org/?lang=ru)

Comment: **1)** Софт только для Windows (ув-мый ТС не указал свою ОС). // **2)** Разработка прекратилась, см. [**неутешительную статистику багтрекера**](https://sourceforge.net/p/winmerge/bugs/).

Answer (score 3):

Имеет смысл присмотреться к этим программам, они специально заточены для программистов. Meld, например, я использую как внешнюю утилиту для просмотра/слияний изменений в IDE. Плюч все бесплатные и работают на нескольких платформах.

1. [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/)
2. [p4merge](https://www.perforce.com/product/components/perforce-visual-merge-and-diff-tools)
3. [TkDiff](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tkdiff/)
4. [Diffuse](http://diffuse.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 2):

Рекомендую посмотреть [Araxis Merge](http://www.araxis.com/merge/index.en) - приятный интерфейс и хороший функционал. Больше всего мне пока понравилось использование фильтров и регулярок в сравнениях.

Comment: Существенный недостаток для пользователей — программа платная, не опенсорс.

Answer (score 2):

В Linux-системах [kdiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) идеальное решение считаю

Comment: Слово "идеальный" лучше не употреблять совсем.

Comment: после "идеальный" есть слово "считаю", поэтому, в данном контексте, считаю его уместным. Могу перефразировать: "идеальное на мой взгляд"  :)

Comment: Почему только для linux ? она на  Windows  тоже работает, я ей xml файлы сравниваю, очень удобно.