# Алгоритм сравнения текстов

Tags: c#, winforms

Здравствуйте, пишу программу, в которой одной из главных функций будет сравнение двух html файлов. (допустим проверка изменений в тегах )

Программу пишу на c# (WinForms) и зашёл в тупик.

Ни у кого случайно нету предположений или уже готовых решений по этому поводу?

Всё должно выглядеть примерно так (показывает что удалил, что изменил и что добавил): http://text.num2word.ru/

Схожие программы в этом посте: [Кликабельно (ссылка)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/532499/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Comment: На том же сайте есть внизу слева ссылка на программы-"источники вдохновения". С исходниками. В посте "схожие программы" тоже есть ссылки на другие программы с исходниками.

Comment: Изучайте алгоритмы работы функций Megree и/или Diff (Гугл в помощь, инфы валом) Готовым решением тут врятли кто-то поделится. В лучшем случае ссылка на общедоступные исходники, которые не менее легко гуглятся чем алгоритм сравнения. 
Ежели у вас какие вопросы по реализации алгоритма, то приведите код и опишите проблему детально.

Comment: [Diff, Match and Patch libraries for Plain Text](https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/)